# Reconocer palabras en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

estoy trabado en este problema.

*Your little brother has just learnt to write one, two and three, in English. He has written a lot of those words in a paper, your task is to recognize them. Note that your little brother is only a child, so he may make small mistakes: for each word, there might be at most one wrong letter. The word length is always correct. It is guaranteed that each letter he wrote is in lower-case, and each word he wrote has a unique interpretation.*

**Input**

*The first line contains the number of words that your little brother has written. Each of the following lines contains a single word with all letters in lower-case. The words satisfy the constraints above: at most one letter might be wrong, but the word length is always correct. There will be at most 1000 words in the input.*

**Output**

For each test case, print the numerical value of the word.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
texto=str(input())
lista=texto.split()

for i in lista:
    if len(i)==5:
        print("3")
    if len(i)==3 and 
        print("2")
    else:
        print("1")
```

Aclaro que soy muy novato estoy usando Python 3.x, lo que quiero saber es si existe alguna funcion que me permita diferenciar las letras porque en el caso del 1 y 2 tienen la misma longitud la palabra. De antemanos gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Primero, hagamos un análisis:

El problema dice que el niño escribirá una palabra que represente un numero, y esta palabra tendrá como ***maximo*** una letra equivocada, por lo cual podemos deducir, que ***siempre habrá dos letras*** que sean correctas en la palabra.

Aplicando esto, podemos dividir la entrada de texto en una lista que contenga sus letras, por ejemplo:

```
entrada = 'too'
division = ['t','o','o']
```

y comparar las letras de esta división con las letras de un numero original, por ejemplo "two":

O sea comparar `['t','o','o']` con `['t','w','o']`.

Como siempre habrán dos letras que sean iguales, si el numero de coincidencias es igual a dos, entonces, en este caso, la palabra escrita por el niño corresponde a 2, en caso contrario, por descarte, es 1. De tener mas digitos es 3

Aplicandolo a codigo seria:

```
texto = str(input("Tu numero es: "))
texto_dividido = []
for i in texto:  # Aca se divide la frase en letras
    texto_dividido.append(i)
letras_one = ["o","n","e"] # Base que usaremos para comparar

contador_comparativo = 0  # Para contar la cantidad de coincidencias

contador_indice = 0  # Para avanzar en la lista
if len(texto) == 5:
    print ("3")
else:
    for i in letras_one: # Se comparan las letras de el numero original
                         # con las de la frase del usuario

        if i == texto_dividido[contador_indice]:
            contador_comparativo += 1
        contador_indice += 1
    if contador_comparativo == 2:
        print ("1")
    else: # Si no hay 2 coincidencias, por descarte es 2
        print ("2")
```

Mismo código sin tanto comentario:

```
texto = str(input("Tu numero es: "))
texto_dividido = []
for i in texto:
    texto_dividido.append(i)
letras_one = ["o","n","e"]
contador_comparativo = 0  
contador_indice = 0
if len(texto) == 5:
    print ("3")
else:
    for i in letras_one:
        if i == texto_dividido[contador_indice]:
            contador_comparativo += 1
        contador_indice += 1
    if contador_comparativo == 2:
        print ("1")
    else:
        print ("2")
```

Salida con "nwo" (*two*):

```
>>> Tu numero es: nwo
2
```

Salida con "ine" (*one*):

```
>>> Tu numero es: ine
1
```

***Saludos***

Comment: Power revise la edición que sugeriste a la pregunta que respondes, te pido no alteres el contenido, claramente el usuario intenta realizar un ejercicio con contenido en inglés; eso es correcto además su  pregunta esta en español, por favor para futuras ediciones que sean relevantes como dar formato al código por ejemplo

Comment: Ok. Tomo nota de la sugerencia, gracias.